# How to inject a bean to another bean declaration in another class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

```
file-a.java

package com.abcd.common;
import com.xyz.HCStrategy;
import com.xyz.DHC;

@Configuration
public class HCConfig {
    @Bean
    public HCStrategy dHC() {
        return new DHC();
    }
}



file-b.java

package com.abcd.app;
public class SCConfig {
   @Bean
   public meow() {
     //I want to call dHC here
   }

}
```

One way is to create an autowire for HCConfig and then use the object to call dHC. However, I want to directly auto wire dHC from file-b and use it without creating an object of HCConfig. I can autowire HCStrategy, but it does not work since it is an import and not my own class.

Comment: Just put it in as a method argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
file-b.java

package com.abcd.app;
@Component
public class SCConfig {
   private final HCStrategy hcStrategy;

   @Autowired
   public SCConfig(HCStrategy hcStrategy){
       this.hcStrategy = hcStrategy;
   }

   public [return type] meow() {
     //you can use here hcStrategy bean
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain what it is you want to achieve, but it sounds like you just need HCStrategy whithin SCConfig. In your code SCConfig isn't actually a Spring Configuration because @Configuration is missing. Unless of course you don't use component scanning here but an import. If HCConfig is importet, HCStrategy is in your application context thus you can autowire it like in the example below in SCConfig.

```
file-a.java

package com.abcd.common;
import com.xyz.HCStrategy;
import com.xyz.DHC;

@Configuration
public class HCConfig {

    @Bean
    public HCStrategy dHC() {
        return new DHC();
    }
}

file-b.java

package com.abcd.app;

@Configuration
public class SCConfig {

    @Bean
    public meow(HCStrategy hcsStrategy) {
      ...
   }
}
```